# C#. Connecting to Service-based database from another computer

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I created a local database for my program, which is intended to be server-side application. Server is going to have local static IP Address 192.168.x.x. On my server itself, program connects to service-based database just fine. But how can i connect to it from another computer and different program in LAN? Is it only in connection string that i should change, or should i make adjustments in server-side as well?

Comment: From my understanding, no matter your application and your database are in the same LAN or not the only thing you should change is connection string, but if they are on the same LAN the ip address starts with 192.168.x.x, different machines in different LAN u should get the valid ip address of the database server

Comment: You should have connection string. In connection string there should be IP or servername, port, username, database name... This site might be helpful https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: @Behzad How my connection string would have to look like? Or where can i find it?

Comment: something like this "Server=[myServerAddress];Database=[myDataBase];User ID=[myUsername];
Password=[myPassword];" as @Josef suggested the best place to read about connection strings is connectionstrings.com

Comment: It is, thank you.
1. What if my database does not have user ID and password?
2. Does the software find the database automatically on the computer with no directory specified?

Comment: no, you must provide username / pwd.